# Using component as props in dispatch inside useEffect gives infinite dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi can you explain why this is happening , i tried to call a dispatch(action) then pass a component props even though I use empty array dependancy it continues to fire the dispatch again and again.Thanks.

```
useEffect(()=>{
dispatch(action(<Somecomponent />))

},[])
```

Comment: You will need to add a lot more context for that to make sense.
Basically, your component itself seems to unmount and remount very often, which might be explained by you adding a `key` prop to it that changes from render to render or declaring that component within another component, which will lead to it being a "different" component each render.

Comment: I don't think you should dispatch jsx in actions unless you are doing it for middleware. If you save jsx in state you are definitely doing something wrong. If you only console.log in the effect does the component remount? If not then you should check why the parent is re rendering and re mounting the component that has the effect and dispatches the action.

Comment: Hi , Im trying to set my modal turn on the background using dispatch then asigning a content/card inside the modal using dispatch passing component.

Why cant i pass a component inside a dispatch? thanks

Comment: Generally, we recommend only to store serializable data in Redux, JSX and functions are not serializable. For your modal, usually just using a Portal should do the trick without any global state shenanigans.